# Style the container of React Native's FlatList items separate from the header / footer?

Tags: react-native

I have a `FlatList` using the `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent`.

Is there a way to style a container of the items (which come from the `data` prop), but not include the header and footer with in?

https://snack.expo.io/@jamesweblondon/bold-pretzel

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";

const exampleData = [...Array(20)].map((d, index) => ({
  key: `item-${index}`,
  label: index,
  backgroundColor: `rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${
    index * 5
  }, ${132})`,
}));

const Example = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: item.backgroundColor,
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "white",
            fontSize: 32,
            height: 100,
          }}
        >
          {item.label}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={exampleData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "grey",
              height: 200,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>Before list</Text>
          </View>
        }
        ListFooterComponent={
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "grey",
              height: 200,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>After list</Text>
          </View>
        }
      />
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "gold",
          height: 200,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Text>Footer</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Id like an element allowing me to wrap `data` so I can add padding, border, etc:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `columnWrapperStyle` prop instead of `contentContainerStyle` prop of FlatList. This will help you to make styling of the wrapper of the components generated from the data.

For demo just add border property and you will see this will only apply styles to the container of items and not to `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent`
Example

```
<FlatList
    ....
    columnWrapperStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red'}}
/>
```

Note: Please make sure as the name of the prop suggests, the style will be applied to each colum. Also if this prop does not work for you then consider using `numColumns` prop of FlatList first then apply style with `columnWrapperStyle`

Comment: This is great for when you have more than one column, but doesn't work with one, which seems to be what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `contentContainerStyle` prop in `FlatList`, it should help you do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: contentContainerStyle wraps the header and footer as well. I need just the items rendered from the data prop to be wrapped.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The only solution that comes to mind is doing something like [this](https://snack.expo.io/I1V0dznZy). It's kinda hacky but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that works for me, but I'm not sure if it can cause performance issues, so beware.

The idea is to have two FlatLists, where the one containing your actual list is the `FooterListComponent` of the other one.

N.B. *notice how it's not a FlatList wrapped in a ScrollView, which would trigger the `Virtualizedlists should never be nested inside plain scrollviews` error.*

Here's the code

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

return (
 <FlatList
        data={[]}
        renderItem={() => undefined}
        ListHeaderComponent={ListHeader} // whatever you want above your list
        ListFooterComponent={() => {
          return (
            <View style={yourContainerStyle}>
                <FlatList
                  data={data}
                  renderItem={renderItem}
                />
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />)
}
```